# Information of Informatica jobs for last 30 days

Tags: informatica

I want to get the date, time and sequence of all the Informatica jobs running on  dev server for the last 30 days. How can we get it?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be query on rep_sess_log in Infromatica metadatabase (see Repository Guide).

```
SELECT 
SUBJECT_AREA, WORKFLOW_NAME,MAPPING_NAME,
SUCCESSFUL_SOURCE_ROWS, FAILED_SOURCE_ROWS 
ACTUAL_START, SESSION_TIMESTAMP END_TIME
FROM REP_SESS_LOG
WHERE 
ACTUAL_START BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/JAN/2021','dd/mon/yyyy') AND
TO_DATE('31/JAN/2021','dd/mon/yyyy');
```